# Invoice model & view in rails - how to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, invoice

I want to create an invoice in rails. Invoice can have items and each item will have quantity & price. It's a typical invoice we see everyday.

In order to create an invoice what is the best approach.

1. What is the common model for invoice and items?
2. As i see items will be a separate model. But how can we have one view for invoice, which creates both the invoice and items added to it?

For example i want to create something like this sample invoice form: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gal/screenshots/48841

---

**Update:**

In addition to the answer following links are useful for solving the problem:
Invoice example: https://github.com/linkworks/invoices

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Also ryan bates has created a rails plugin for same purpose!: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

---

**Update 2:**

Another solution exactly what i was looking for:
[Google cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3abtvYqC7d_-oJ%3aiqbalfarabi.net/2011/01/20/rails-nested-form-with-has-many-through-association/%20&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have an Invoice model, an Item model, and a model that links them together where you can save quantity, price, etc:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_items
  has_many :items, :through => :invoice_items
end

class InvoiceItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_items
  has_many :invoices, :through => :invoice_items
end
```

The InvoiceItem model would contain any data that is relavent to the link between an invoice and an item. This would include things like price, quantity, discount, or anything else you might have.

To answer your second question about having single view, I could expose this via a Invoice resource.

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id]).includes(:invoice_items => :items)
  end
end
```

Then your view could iterate over the items:

```
<% @invoice.invoice_items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.quantity %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. For second question how can we create a new invoice with items. As i vaguely understand we need to use partials?

Comment: Yes, you can use partials and I highly recommend it, but it's not required. The reason I didn't get into that in my answer is because it's a little harder to explain and the point I was trying to get across is that you're just iterating over the items.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I found an example application on the same lines: https://github.com/linkworks/invoices

Comment: Also relavant rails casts http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2